# creating a multiindex dataframe from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

So I have a dataframe (df) that looks like this:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2018-01-02 | 43.06 | 111.80 | 147.47 | 45.54 | 85.95 |
| 2018-01-03 | 43.07 | 112.28 | 151.52 | 45.44 | 86.35 |
| 2018-01-04 | 43.26 | 112.23 | 154.59 | 46.08 | 87.11 |
| 2018-01-05 | 43.75 | 111.62 | 155.34 | 46.07 | 88.19 |
| 2018-01-06 | 43.75 | 111.62 | 155.34 | 46.07 | 88.19 |
| 2018-01-07 | 43.75 | 111.62 | 155.34 | 46.07 | 88.19 |
| 2018-01-08 | 43.59 | 110.02 | 156.28 | 46.00 | 88.28 |
| 2018-01-09 | 43.58 | 109.94 | 156.63 | 46.23 | 88.22 |
| 2018-01-10 | 43.57 | 109.47 | 156.96 | 46.07 | 87.82 |
| 2018-01-11 | 43.82 | 110.99 | 156.98 | 46.04 | 88.08 |

The index is datetime, the columns are tickers and the values closing prices.

Im trying to make a multiindex dataframe from it by adding another level of (9) columns. For example, the 9 new columns of the second level would be called 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

It would look like this (cant fit anything after C on the page...):

|  | A |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | B |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 1 |
| 2018-01-02 | 43.06 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 111.80 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 147.47 |
| 2018-01-03 | 43.07 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 112.28 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 151.52 |
| 2018-01-04 | 43.26 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 112.23 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 154.59 |
| 2018-01-05 | 43.75 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 111.62 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 155.34 |

The original closing price value from df date/ticker would be placed in the same date row, in column1 under each ticker.

The values that would go in the second level, 2-9, would be a calculation based on actual, and future prices.

Basically, if we take any row, call the date 'Dn', the 2s columns would all be the closing price on D(n+1) minus the closing price on Dn. The 5s columns would all be closing price on D(n+4) - closing price on Dn. The 9s column = price on D(n+8) - Dn.

For example, A2 on D1 (2018-01-02) would be (A on D2 minus - A on D1), or 43.07-43.06. A3 would be (A on D3 minus A on D1) or 43.26-43.06. A9 would be A on D9 (2018-01-10) minus A on D1, or 43.57 - 43.06.

Obviously, the last 8 or 9 days would be missing values, as they all require between 1 and 8 future prices that havent happened yet.

How can I make this adaptation of df? I thought it would be pretty straight forward, but so far its beyond my skills. Ive tried multiindex from frame and product, but none works, I keep getting length missmatch. The tutorials Ive found are all relatively simple, making the multiindex when you know the values, not making an empty multiindex that you put calculated values in.

Also, assuming I want to update this dataframe each day with a new row, would I have to concat it to the original df and remake the multiindex, or is there a way to add the new row of data straight into the multiindex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df_out = df.assign(col=1).set_index('col', append=True).unstack()
df_out.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_out.columns.levels[0], 
                                           np.arange(1,10)]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                A                                       B  ...   D      E       
                1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9       1  ...   9      1   2   
Date                                                       ...                  
2018-01-02  43.06 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  111.80  ... NaN  85.95 NaN  \
2018-01-03  43.07 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  112.28  ... NaN  86.35 NaN   
2018-01-04  43.26 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  112.23  ... NaN  87.11 NaN   
2018-01-05  43.75 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  111.62  ... NaN  88.19 NaN   
2018-01-06  43.75 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  111.62  ... NaN  88.19 NaN   
2018-01-07  43.75 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  111.62  ... NaN  88.19 NaN   
2018-01-08  43.59 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  110.02  ... NaN  88.28 NaN   
2018-01-09  43.58 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  109.94  ... NaN  88.22 NaN   
2018-01-10  43.57 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  109.47  ... NaN  87.82 NaN   
2018-01-11  43.82 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  110.99  ... NaN  88.08 NaN   

                                        
             3   4   5   6   7   8   9  
Date                                    
2018-01-02 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
2018-01-03 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
2018-01-04 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
2018-01-05 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
2018-01-06 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
2018-01-07 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
2018-01-08 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
2018-01-09 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
2018-01-10 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
2018-01-11 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  

[10 rows x 45 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott. Its not quite what Im trying to do, but seems like it might be part of it, so Ill try it out and see if I can add in the calculations. Also, Ill try and work out what each bit of the code is doing, so itll be a great tutorial. Thanks!